How to activate my Wifi USB key TP Archer T2U
I'm new to Ubuntu, and have it now on my desktop, as the device isn't equipped with wifi, I purchased a wifi key of Tp-Link, a (Archer T2U), but it's provided with Windows pilote, things I missed, then now I'm stuck with it and have no clou on where to find the pilote of the USB key for the Ubuntu, and how to install, if someone please could be very kind and me on this, thank you very much

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; mokutil --sb

We need the output of lsusb to know the chip which can vary even with the same product.

It's not clear if you have tried simply plugging it in and seeing if it just works.  When asking for technical help, please describe what you tried, what happened (including any error messages), what you were trying to achieve and whether you were following a guide.
